# How to Get Related Products in custom module admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, grid, grid-serlization, products

I am working on Magento custom module admin grid I want to show product id and related product id and other product information.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Can you provide more info about this?

Comment: @Sukeshini i want a page in Admin where I can enter product ID, I can see all related products associated with it and edit the list(add and delete the related produts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try on this.

Assume you want to find the related products of $product_id.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = $model->load($product_id);

// Get all related product ids of $product.
$allRelatedProductIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();

foreach ($allRelatedProductIds as $id) {
            $relatedProduct = $model->load($id);

            // get Product's name
            echo $relatedProduct->getName();

            // get product's short description
            echo $relatedProduct->getShortDescription();

            // get Product's Long Description
            echo $relatedProduct->getDescription();

            // get Product's Regular Price
            echo $relatedProduct->getPrice();

            // get Product's Special price
            echo $relatedProduct->getSpecialPrice();

            // get Product's Url
            echo $relatedProduct->getProductUrl();

            // get Product's image Url
            echo $relatedProduct->getImageUrl();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple add the below code in your custom module tab.php file.

```
 $this->addTab('related', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Products'),
            'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/related', array('_current' => true)),
            'class'     => 'ajax',
 ));
```

and run your module.

Hope you got the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
$RelProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p_id)->getRelatedProductIds();
echo "<div class='product clearfix'>";
foreach ($RelProduct as $id) {
    $Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    echo "<div class='product__item' style='float: left;'>"."<a href='#' class='product__link'>";
    echo "<img src=".$relatedProduct->getImageUrl()." width='200' height='200' />"."</br>";
    echo $Product->getName()."</br>";
    echo $Product->getDescription()."</br>";
    echo $Product->getPrice()."</br>";
    echo "</a></div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
?>
```